# Mongo DB replication

Tags: mongodb, replication, nosql

Im a total newbie to MongoDB and was watching some videos and really liked the replication setup that Mongo offers.

**Scenario**

I want to know if the following scenario is possible with MongoDB.

lets say I have 3 MongoDB servers

1. a server in the Cloud (CloudMongo)
2. 2 servers running on 2 terminal machines (T1 and T2)

The CloudMongo has a database called Enterprise with Tables AllSales and Promotions
The Terminal machines both have databases POS with tables Sales and Promotions

**Questions**

1. Can CloudMongo replicate a subset of the Promotions data to T1 and another subset to T2?
2. Can Terminals T1 and T2 replicate their sales data to be consolidated to the AllSales table/collection on CloudMongo?

Comment: Sounds like you want sharding, that can support containment of collections to specific servers in a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication in Mongo is for data durability (and in some cases, read scaling).  It's not meant for application-level data management.  Selective replication is not supported.

Collections in the data path of the servers in the replica set will be replicated in their entirety.

It sounds like what you want to do is copy certain pieces of data around to different members of your set.  This is certainly automatable at the application level by building specific queries.

Comment: OK I see, I really love the fail over when the primary goes down guess i'm going to have to write the application code as opposed to using replication

Comment: @MikeM: Not necessarily.  For replication, womp's statement is absolutely correct. However, there is [tag aware sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/) and it basically works like this: You define subsets of the [shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key) which ought to be saved on defined shards. However, this comes at a rather hefty price: Each shard should consist of a replica set and you need exactly 3 additional config servers. So we would at least talk of 12 nodes in the setup you want (3*3 for the rs + 3)

Comment: @Marcus That is pretty expensive of a truth, but at least i am aware of it as an option